# Find size of binary file, function tellg() returns -1

Tags: c++, fstream

I've written a function which initialize some fields of FileDataTransfer object and also finds size of file.

Here is a code:

```
bool FileTransferData::initialize(const string& fileName, string& errMsg)
{
   if (this->transferInProgress)
   {
       errMsg = "\nFile Transfer already in progress. File Transfer Request denied.\a";
       return false;
   }
   this->inFileStream.open(fileName, ios::binary | ios::ate);
   if (!inFileStream.is_open())
   {
       errMsg = "\nRequested file: " + fileName + " does not exist or was not found.\a";
       return false;
   }
   this->fileName = fileName;
   this->fileSize = (int)this->inFileStream.tellg();
   this->inFileStream.seekg(0);
   this->fileOffset = 0;
   this->transferInProgress = true;
   return true;
}
```

But field this->fileSize become -1 after completion of my function, I think tellg() returns -1, but why ?

Comment: Once upon a time, people used to call `stat()` to get the size of a file, but now, for some reason, they `seek()` to the far end and then use `tell()` to get the position. It looks to me like you forgot to seek to the far end maybe?

Comment: Replace the fileSize data type with  std::ifstream::pos_type, if it solves your problem

Comment: No, it doesn't help((

Comment: Which compiler you use?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2017

Comment: 1. You should use [std::istream::pos_type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) for positions, not int...    2. Can't reproduce your error, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1c50816b7f56557 ... 3. is_open only checks for a handle. try to use [fail()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/) to see if your file is open properly...

Comment: Which is the type of inFileStream? In my case using `fstream` it returns -1 while using `ifstream` it returns the correct file length. Alternatively, you could use `fstream` but should open the file adding the `ios::in` flag.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get the size of a file like this

```
long long filesize(const char *fname)
{
   int ch;
   FILE *fp;
   long long answer = 0;
   fp = fopen(fname, "rb");
   if(!fp)
     return -1;
   while( (ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
      answer++;
   fclose(fp);
   return answer;
}
```

It's portable, and whilst it does a pass over the file, usually you'll have to pass through the file anyway, so you're not blowing up the big O efficiency of your function. Plus fgetc() is highly optimised for buffering.

Comment: -1 sorry, but this is just bad advice, to get the filesize by literally counting the bytes. it's true you have to usually pass through the file, but the size is usually needed before you pass through the file -> double pass through. also, or more important, '-1' is an error code indicating something is wrong. creating a workaround instead of searching&solving the problem is suboptimal. you also could `find / -not -name '/path/to/my/file' -print0 | xargs -0 rm --; df / | cut -f3 -d' '` **(DON'T DO THAT!!!!)**.

Answer (score 0):

The `-1` value for [`std::istream::tellg`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/tellg/) indicates an error which you can check with `std::ios::fail` and `std::ios::bad` member functions:

> If either the stream buffer associated to the stream does not support the operation, or if it fails, the function returns -1.

I couldn't reproduce the error so I intend to suggest you another approach. The platform you use knows the size of your file and many more about it (last access time, etc.). The following example shows how to determine the size of a file in a platform dependent way (like the `boost::filesystem::file_size` does too):

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#endif

#include <cstdint>

intmax_t fsizeof(const std::string& fileName) {
    intmax_t fileSize = -1;

#ifdef _WIN32
    WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA fileData;

    if(GetFileAttributesEx(fileName.c_str(), GetFileExInfoStandard, &fileData) && 
            !(fileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) {
        fileSize = fileData.nFileSizeHigh;
        fileSize <<= sizeof(fileData.nFileSizeLow) * 8;
        fileSize += fileData.nFileSizeLow;
    }
#else
    struct stat fileStat;

    if(stat(fileName.c_str(), &fileStat) == 0 && S_ISREG(fileStat.st_mode))
        fileSize = fileStat.st_size;
#endif

    return fileSize;
}
```